# Java has the weirdest error

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-tree

When I run the following code:

```
class zTree<T>
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> table = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
    int height = 0;

    <T> void zTree(BinaryTree<T> tree)
    {
        recIt((BinaryTree<T>)tree, 1);
    }

    void recIt(BinaryTree<T> tree, int fromRoot)
    {
        if(!(tree.isEmpty()))
        {
            ArrayList<T> tempList = (ArrayList<T>)table.get(fromRoot);
            tempList.add((T)tree.getData()); // add data to table
            recIt(tree.left,fromRoot+1); // recursive left,
            recIt(tree.right,fromRoot+1); // right
        }
        else
        {
            height = fromRoot-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Javac returns this error.

```
zTree.java:15: recIt(structures.tree.BinaryTree<T>,int) in zTree<T> cannot be applied to (structures.tree.BinaryTree<T>,int)
        recIt((BinaryTree<T>)tree, 1);
        ^
1 error
```

I don't care about he efficiency of my code. I care to understand what is going wrong but javac is clearly not much help for once as it's telling me that (x,y) can not be applied to (x,y) ... but why?

Comment: _Java has gone insane. ._ no, maybe your code is wrong, don't blame Java for it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `T` in the `zTree` *method* (which bizarrely has the same name as its enclosing class - don't do that) isn't the same as the `T` in the `zTree` *class*, because the method is generic:

```
<T> void zTree(BinaryTree<T> tree)
```

If you make it *not* generic, it should be fine, as now the `T` type parameter within the method will mean the same as the `T` in the method you're calling.

```
void zTree(BinaryTree<T> tree)
```

I would *strongly* advise use to start following Java naming conventions, and *definitely* don't create any methods with the same name as the class in which they're declared.

If that method was *meant* to be a constructor, you should get rid of the return type:

```
zTree(BinaryTree<T> tree)
```

(And still fix the class name.)

Comment: Thank you very much! One would think that java could check this and give a better error. Though I will note this for next time.

Comment: @gabeio: It won't if you just have `zTree(BinaryTree<T> tree)`... if you really say that it is, I suggest you ask a new question with *just* that problem. (Get rid of `recIt` for the new question - but fix the class name, ideally.)

Comment: Actually I realized that the capitalization was different from the class name by accident thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

You are declare the method `zTree` generic when you say

```
<T> void zTree(BinaryTree<T> tree)
```

I suspect that you wanted to create a constructor.  If so, don't use a return type.  However, you've already declared your class generic; just use your class's `T`:

```
zTree(BinaryTree<T> tree)
```

Additionally, conventionally, Java class names start with an uppercase letter, e.g. `ZTree`.